# Nested setOnClickListener in Java / Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to setup a onclicklistner on a dialog button. If the listener is set using

```
bnxt.setOnClickListener(new x());
```

the app works as expected but if the below given 2nd implementation is used, the app crashes. Any hint or help is highly appreciated.

```
bnxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ...
```

Supplied code:

```
class x implements OnClickListener {
    x() {
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (listener != null) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            FancyButton m_no = (FancyButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.b_no);
            m_no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
```

}

```
public View onCView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_x, container, false);
    final FancyButton bnxt = (FancyButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup);

  //bnxt.setOnClickListener(new x());

    bnxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (listener != null) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                FancyButton m_no = (FancyButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.b_no);

           m_no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting.

Comment: @pop No errors except thread crashes in logcat.

Comment: FancyButton m_no = (FancyButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup); --> X listener.

FancyButton m_no = (FancyButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.b_no); --> onclicklistener.

which one is right ?

Comment: @pop I have edited the code and it's correct now.

Comment: I had tried the same there is no problem in creating nested listener. you need to check your code whats going wrong. If you want I will post my sample code what i have created.

Comment: @pop You mean the 2nd method of invocation is working fine?

Comment: yes . I put a toast inside the click of 2nd listener its showing.

Comment: are you setting your custom dialog layout to your dialog ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174069/discussion-between-pop-and-shahzad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with using a nested onClicklistener. Below is the sample code. Kept layout as simple just to test.

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

            view.findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);
                    dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Dialog btn clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
```

fragment_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivityFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="btn2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

dialog_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dialog BTn" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```